# color is incorrect when draw metal triangles with an alpha color. such as (0.9,0.6,0,0.4)

Tags: ios, metal

```
vertex Vertex
line_vertex_main(device Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                 constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                 uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
  float4x4 matrix = uniforms.matrix;
  Vertex in = vertices[vid];
  Vertex out;
  out.position = matrix * float4(in.position);
  out.color = in.color;
  return out;
}

fragment float4
line_fragment_main(Vertex inVertex [[stage_in]])
{
  return inVertex.color;
}
```

Color is incorrect. `color(0.9,0.6,0,0.4)` in metal transform to a strange color:
**left is correct, right is draw with metal**
[image]

Color is correct when draw metal triangles with a no alpha color, 
**right is draw with metal**.
[image]

Comment: How did you determine that the left drawing is "correct" and the right "incorrect"? Because you've got a non-1.0 alpha, I'm assuming you're blending. The "source over" blending would use (source.r * source.a + dest.r * (1 - source.a)) for red. For your color blended over an opaque white background, that would be (0.9 * 0.4 + 1.0 * (1 - 0.4)) -> (0.9 * 0.4 + 1.0 * 0.6) -> (0.36 + 0.6) -> 0.96. Doing the same for the other color components yields (0.96, 0.84, 0.6, 1.0). Enter that into any RGB color viewer and it's pretty close to the color on the right, depending on profile.

Comment: Your colors are not premultiplied. I believe you need to premultiply them first.

Answer (score 0):

Your blending mode is not configured. You could configure blending on your [MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpipelinedescriptor).

Comment: thanks~:)
i try blending mode but no use. BUT when blending and red/green/blue part multiply alpha then give it to vertex Array. the color is correct

Comment: when add blending mode, how to fix cover self problem. use depth?